# How do I create a GET with multiple possible parameters

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using **ASP.NET** Web API (4 RTM) and would like to create a method(s) to handle a GET request. Think of this as `GetCustomer()` to handle my GET request.
Now, getting a customer by customer Id is quite simple; I pass the customer Id in the `querystring` and we're off and running. Suppose I want the option to pass one of two possible parameters; an integer representing the customer OR an abbreviation.

One option is to have a single method to handle the GET request for integers and strings. Then, inside the method I could test if the value is able to be parsed as an integer and handle it accordingly. But is this the correct way to handle this situation?

If I should have two separate methods, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use just one entry point to that kind of code:

```
http://example.com/lookupUser?id=18475
http://example.com/lookupUser?userCode=jjs
http://example.com/lookupUser?FullName=Jeremy%20J%20%Starcher
```

Well, maybe not the last example since there could be multiple hits.

Answer (score 0):

From your mention of using a (presumably unique) ID, you might want a separate action method for it. But from your description of a single *intent*, a single controller method is probably the way to go - and note you still wouldn't have to parse strings manually, the MVC model-binder can do that for you.

If you have separate methods, they have to have different URLs. They could be the same method name overloaded, but then they would still have to be decorated with ActionName attributes to assign them different identities. (Note you could use other selector attributes to distinquish, such as [HttpPost] or a custom attribute.)

Note you could also conditionally invoke different controller methods on a URL based on its parameters using a MapRoute (in Global.asax) that expects parameters.

The benefit of handling all the same type of activities in a single place is that the code becomes clearer, more maintainable, and less defect-prone. If you find that isn't the case, then break them up. This is the usual Don't Repeat Yourself/Single Point of Truth/Separation of Reponsibility stuff I'm talking about.

As a general rule I find in MVC that the URL path (without the querystring), the Controller Method, and the intent all break down along the same lines. For example, these two URLs follow that rule:

```
http://example.com/person/id/403
http://example.com/person/search?FirstName=Joe&LastName=Smith
```

We express our intent in the URL to get either a single person or possible multiple matches.

You said you might pass an abbreviation (which doesn't sound like it would be unique), as one of two parameters. If each of the optional parameters were independently unique, then it probably doesn't make sense to form a question for more than one at a time. It would get complex to figure out which method to pass the request to before actually entering the workhorse of your custom controller logic, if you might have a, or b, or a AND b.

Also, technologies like LINQ make it quite easy to dynamically compose your query procedurally to have either or both constraint on the results.

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Search(string FirstName, string LastName) {
     var people = AllPeopleInDatabase();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName)) people=people.Where(p => p.FirstName==FirstName);
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName)) people=people.Where(p => p.LastName==LastName);
     return View(people);
}
```

Putting a unique ID into that mix doesn't make sense to me only because I can't think of a programmatic scenario offhand (except for the fairly unique case of password validation) where you only want to get the specified record if another criteria matches. So, if someone asks for an id and it doesn't exist, it is probably an error case, where if someone searches by criteria that don't yield results, it probably is not an error case. But still, you could:

```
public ViewResult Search(string FirstName, string LastName, int? id) {
```

edit: Also note that the model-binder will handle properties on classes, and that's the typical way to bind multiple parameters:

```
public ViewResult Search(MyCriteriaViewModel criteria) {
```

edit2: also note that RESTful services (which WebAPI is ideally suited to) have standard practices for CRUD URLs. The following is from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations :

```
Action                      HTTP method  Relative URI
Get a list of all products  GET          /api/products
Get a product by ID         GET          /api/products/id
Get a product by category   GET          /api/products?category=category
Create a new product        POST         /api/products
Update a product            PUT          /api/products/id
Delete a product            DELETE       /api/products/id
```

Good luck!